# To use the output of a lookup activity to query the db and write to a csv file in storage account usin ADF

Tags: azure, azure-storage, etl, azure-data-factory

My requirement is to use ADF to read data (columnA) from an xlx/csv file which is in the storage account and use that (columnA) to query my db and the output of my query which includes (columnA) should be written to a file in storage account.

I was able to read the data from the storage account but getting it as table. I Need to use it as a individual entry like select * from table where id=columnA.

Then the next task if I'm able to read each data, how to write it to a file

I used lookup activity to read data from excel, the below is the sample output, I need to use only the sku number for my query next, not able to proceed with this. Kindly suggest a solution

[image]

I set a variable as the output of the lookup as suggested here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6185/azure-data-factory-lookup-activity-example/ and tried to use that variable in my query, but I'm getting exception when I trigger it, bad template error.

Comment: which sql you use,like `select * from xxx where xx = 'sk1234'`?And are there only 3 count in your really scenario?

Comment: Yes that would be my preferred sql, no there will be many records

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:
I create a sample like yours and there is no need to use `set variable`.

[image]

Details:

Below is `lookup` output:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "value": [
        {
            "SKU": "aaaa"
        },
        {
            "SKU": "bbbb"
        },
        {
            "SKU": "ccc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Setting of `copy data activity`:

[image]

Query sql:

```
select * from data_source_table where Name = '@{activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].SKU}'
```

You can also use this sql,if you need:

```
select * from data_source_table where Name in('@{activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].SKU}','@{activity('Lookup1').output.value[1].SKU}','@{activity('Lookup1').output.value[2].SKU}')
```

This is my test data in my `SQL DataBase`:

[image]

Here is the result:

```
1,"aaaa",0,2017-09-01 00:56:00.0000000
2,"bbbb",0,2017-09-02 05:23:00.0000000
```

Hope this can help you.

**Update:**

You can try to use DataFlow.

[image: dataflow]

source1 is your `csv` file,source2 is `SQL DataBase`.

This is setting of `lookup`

[image: lookup]

Filter condition:`!isNull(PersonID)`(One column in your SQL DataBase.)

Then,use `select` delete the SKU column.

Finally,Output to single file.

Comment: this looks nice, yes this works did have a try. The output of the lookup may be around 50k or 100k, so harcoding the index will not do the trick,  can you help me to find a way in the index part of the value array

Comment: if I can get all the values is also fine in the same query, like the way you mentioned in the 2 query, but dynamically

Comment: Wait a sec, @Steve check this out "The Lookup activity has a maximum of 5,000 rows, and a maximum size of 2 MB." found in on the Microsoft docs. If this is the case it will not help my situation.

Comment: I update my answer and you can have a try.I success with my sample.